# How to set same class objects in other object of same class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, java-8

I want to optimize this code as i can have multiple parents and childs(self join in hibernate). I want some parents to set in childs. For example event is a parent and it may have nth childs like Edit, create, update, Delete. While some parents like Deals, Movies and Resturant may or may not have childs. Is there any way to write generic code

```
        Privilege parent = new Privilege("Event");
        Privilege parent1 = new Privilege("Deals");
        Privilege parent2 = new Privilege("Movies");
        Privilege parent3 = new Privilege("Restaurant");

        Privilege parent4 = new Privilege("Outdoor");

        Privilege child = new Privilege("Create");
        child.setParentId(parent);

        Privilege child1 = new Privilege("Edit");
        child1.setParentId(parent);

        Privilege child2 = new Privilege("Update");
        child2.setParentId(parent);
        Privilege child3 = new Privilege("Delete");
        child3.setParentId(parent);
```

Comment: use builder design pattern , while creating children set parent in it

Comment: @Mandar Dharurkar can you please give some example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create function like this to set Privilege

```
private static List<Privilege> setPrivileges() {

        Privilege parent = setParentPrivilege("Event");
        Privilege parent1 = setParentPrivilege("Deals");
        Privilege parent2 = setParentPrivilege("Movies");
        Privilege parent3 = setParentPrivilege("Restaurant");
        Privilege parent4 = setParentPrivilege("Outdoor");

        Privilege child = setFirstLevel(parent, "Create");
        Privilege child1 = setFirstLevel(parent, "Edit");
        Privilege child2 = setFirstLevel(parent, "Update");
        Privilege child3 = setFirstLevel(parent, "Delete");
        Privilege subchild1 = setSecondLevel(child3,"Sub Delete");

        return Collections.unmodifiableList(
                Arrays.asList(
                        parent,
                        parent1,
                        parent2,
                        parent3,
                        parent4,
                        child,
                        child1,
                        child2,
                        child3,
                        subchild1
        ));
    }

    private static Privilege setParentPrivilege(String name) {
        return new Privilege(name);
    }

    private static Privilege setFirstLevel(Privilege firstLevel, String name) {
        Privilege firstLevelChild = setParentPrivilege(name);
        firstLevelChild.setParentId(firstLevel);
        return firstLevelChild;
    }

    private static Privilege setSecondLevel(Privilege secondLevel, String name) {
        Privilege secondLevelChild = new Privilege(name);
        secondLevelChild.setParentId(secondLevel);
        return secondLevelChild;
    }
```

Comment: i will try this, but can you simplfiy it using builder patterns

Comment: @Mandar Dharurkar have a look at this i want to convert this to builder pattern as mention by you

Answer (score 0):

I tried to sample code with @superBuilder and @builder
this will reduce some lines of code.
More details : https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-builder-inheritance

```
  @SuperBuilder
    public class Child extends Parent {
       private String a;
       private int b;
       private boolean c;
    }

    @SuperBuilder
    public class Parent {
        private double d;
        private float e;
        private String parentId;

    }

    Child instance = Child.builder().b(7).e(6.3).parentId(parentId).build();
```

Comment: I am implementing self join in hibernate in which i need to set same reference to child object of same class

Answer (score 0):

class Privilege {
    String s;

```
public Privilege(String a) {
    this.s = a;
}

public void setParentId(Privilege aa) {
    System.out.println(aa);
}

public void setParents(Privilege... a) {
    for (Privilege aa : a) {
        this.setParentId(aa);
    }
}
```

}

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] sre) {
    Privilege parent = new Privilege("Event");
    Privilege parent1 = new Privilege("Deals");
    Privilege parent2 = new Privilege("Movies");
    Privilege parent3 = new Privilege("Restaurant");

    Privilege child = new Privilege("Create");
    Privilege child1 = new Privilege("Edit");
    Privilege child2 = new Privilege("Update");
    Privilege child3 = new Privilege("Delete");
    parent.setParents(child,child1,child3,child2);
}
```

}